# Accessing cloudinary API in c# is unauthorized

Tags: c#, api, cloudinary

I'm trying to access a cloudinary API url using `httpclient` class in c#, and here's my code :

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("GetOverlayBrochure")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBrochure(int tourOperatorProfileId, int bookingTemplateId) {


        if (!db.TourOperatorProfiles.Any(t => t.Id == tourOperatorProfileId)) {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if(!db.BookingTemplates.Any(b => b.Id == bookingTemplateId)) {
            return NotFound();
        }


        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://res.cloudinary.com/touresstest");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("image/jpeg"));
        string pathAndQuery = string.Format(
            "image/upload/l_{0},w_0.5,c_scale,g_south_east,y_80,x_50/{1}.jpg",
            tourOperatorProfileId,
            bookingTemplateId
            );

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(pathAndQuery);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            return Ok(response);
        } else {
            return BadRequest(response.ReasonPhrase);
        }



    }
```

But after I accessed the `GetOverlayBrochure` API from Postman, what I got as the response is 400 bad request, and the message is unauthorized.

But if I try access the cloudinary API url from browser or postman, then the result is 200 ok and successful.

My question is :

1. Is it because I did not use the api key in my c# code ?
2. Is it possible to add the api key in the Cloudinary URI, like the api key parameter in google maps api ?

**UPDATE**

I already solve this problem, turns out the `client.BaseAddress` is not work as I expected. Finally I used `WebClient`, not `HttpClient`. I solve this problem by simplify my code to this code below :

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("GetOverlayBrochure")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetBrochure(int tourOperatorProfileId, int bookingTemplateId) {


        if (!db.TourOperatorProfiles.Any(t => t.Id == tourOperatorProfileId)) {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        if (!db.BookingTemplates.Any(b => b.Id == bookingTemplateId)) {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        string pathAndQuery = string.Format(
            "http://res.cloudinary.com/touresstest/image/upload/l_{0},w_0.5,c_scale,g_south_east,y_80,x_50/{1}.jpg",
            tourOperatorProfileId,
            bookingTemplateId
            );

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();

        try {
            byte[] imageBytes = wc.DownloadData(pathAndQuery);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes)) {

                System.Drawing.Image overlayResult = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
                HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray());
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
                return result;

            }
        } catch (Exception) {

            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When delivering images (GET) with Cloudinary, there is no need to use the API keys.

Error 400 usually raised due to invalid URL. 
Please make sure to double check that your code generate a valid URL.

Best,
Yakir

Comment: I get it. Turns out the client.BaseAddress is not work as I expected. I already add my solution to the question. Thank you for your answer !